# Function from Discrete space to arbitrary space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose D is a discrete space, T is a space with the trivial topology, H is a hausdorff space and A is an arbitrary topological space.

a) Show that every map from D to A is continuous.

b) Show that every map from A to T is continuous

c) Show that only continuous maps from T to H are the constant maps.

Proof of a) Our goal is to show that $F: D \rightarrow A $ is continuous. Pick a point $ x \in A$ such that $x = f(y)$ for some $ y\in D. $ Then there exists an open neighborhood $ U \in A $.  Thus $f^{-1}(U) \in D. $ Since $U$ is open in $A$ then it should be immediate that $f^{-1}(U) $ is open in D.

This is what I came up with and for some reason I feel that something is missing in the proof. I'm not sure if there are other things to use to prove this more rigorously. The thing thats throwing me off is knowing how show that an element in the discrete space is open.

Please dismiss Parts b and c since I just put them there to have the problem shown.

Comment: (1) What is your definition of continuity? (2) What are you trying to show for a)? Why are you picking $n$ points – doesn’t one suffice?

Comment: LOL sorry for that. I guess I thought using n points would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that a certain map is continuous $f:D \rightarrow A$ then all you have to do is check that for any open $U \subset A$ its inverseimage is open in $D$ - but since the topology is dicrete - every subset of $D$ is open, in particular any $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in D which shows that $f$ is continuous. When it comes to your idea - why do you choose a finite number of points in $A$? i don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

As an extended comment; consider the extreme case where $D$ is non-empty and finite.  WLOG, let's equip it with a metric $d$ and let's assume that $A$ is a metric space with metric $\rho$.  In this *"down-to-earth special case"* (i.e. metric and not arbitrary topological spaces) we have the nice claim:

> All functions from a discrete metric space $(D,d)$ to an metric space $(A,\rho)$ are Lipschitz.

Suppose that $\#D>1$ since the claim is trivial otherwise.
For every $f:D\rightarrow A$ we have that
$$
\rho(f(x_1),f(x_2)) \le \max_{u,v\in D;\, u\neq v}\,\frac{\rho(f(u),f(v))}{d(u,v)}\, d(x_1,x_2).  
$$
NB, that $\max_{u,v\in D;\, u\neq v}\,\frac{\rho(f(u),f(v))}{d(u,v)}<\infty$ since $u\neq v$ and $D$ is finite.

---

**Intuitions to be gained:**

What I find particularly interpretable about this case:

1. All functions from $(D,d)$ are Lipschitz, and, therefore continuous
2. In general continuous functions on arbitrary metric spaces needn't be of Lipschitz regularity.  So, if you think of $(D,d)$ as approximating an infinite metric space (in the appropriate sense), then you can see that some function's Lipschitz constant will asymptotically explode.

- If the explosion is "local" then that function isn't continuous on
  the "limiting infinite space"
- if that function's explosion is "global" but not "local" then f is continuous but of lower (local) regularity; e.g. Holder or something.